# Valorar si un valor de una celda esta en un rango EXCEL

Tags: excel

Estoy intentando valorar si en una celda cumple estos tres patrones.

a) Si la celda C6 tiene un valor entre 0-400 que en otra celda me ponga Categoría C

b) Si la celda C6 tiene un valor entre 401-800 que en otra celda me ponga Categoría B

c) Si la celda C6 tiene un valor entre 801-Resto de valores que en otra celda me ponga Categoría A

Solo soy capaz de hacer que valore si se cumple la primera y ultima pero no se concatenarlo y tampoco soy capaz de hacer que se valore la condicion entre

=SI(C6<=400;"Categoría C")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día, para este problema debes usar la función **Y** que es un operador lógico entre valores y este agregarlo dentro de tu función **SI** quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
=SI(Y(C6>=401;C6<=800); "Categoria B")
```

te adjunto un sitio en el que se ahonda mas en el tema.
[exceltotal.com](https://exceltotal.com/funcion-si-rangos-valores/)

Saludos.

Comment: perfecto lo pude aplicar lo unico para concatenar varias me da error a la hora de añadir esto. No se si se te ocurre alguna solucion. Gracias de antemano =SI(C6<401;"Categoría C",SI(Y(C6>=401;C6<=800),"Categoria B"SI(C6>800;"Categoría A")))

Comment: =SI(C6<401;"Categoria C";SI(Y(C6>=401;C6<=800);"Categoria B";SI(C6>800;"Categoria A")))

Comment: @UnexpectedCharacter solo te faltaba un **;** entre los SI anidados